# Getting the total number of records of a collection in mongodb using node js + monk + ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, monk

Total noob here, i only know how to do CRUD in Mongodb using node js+monk+ajax but I don't have any idea on how to get the total number of records in my collection.

This is what i have tried so far and it is returning undefined value:

```
router.get('/getTotalrecord'', function (req, res) { 
    var db = req.db; 
    var collection = db.get('department'); 
    res.send(collection.count); 
});
```

Comment: Can you please show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: this is what i have tried so far and it is returning undefined value:  router.get('/getTotalrecord'', function (req, res) {
            var db = req.db;
            var collection = db.get('department');
           res.send(collection.count);
            });
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use this function

```
exports.getCount = (req, res, next) => {
  Users.find({}, { __v: 0 })
    .then(users =>
      res.status(200).json({
        status: true,
        error_num: '',
        result: users.length,
        error: ''
      })
    )
    .catch(err => {
      next(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [`count`](https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/collection/count.html)? It counts how many documents answer a given query:

```
collection.count({})
    .then(count => res.send(count));
```